# Given a person's age x, population's average life span u, predict life span.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given a person's age x, population's average life span u, predict how long person can live? e.g. Say x is 6 and u = 76 one would expect life span of 74.
But when x is 90, for same u = 76, one would expect life span of 94.

Is there a mathematical formula that gives this. Assume normal distribution on population's life span. I'm not sure if standard deviation is needed, but if needed, you can assume it's also given.

Comment: This is too vague.   Actuarial data is a rich and complex subject.  If you want to replace all that with a draw from a normal distribution, fine, but the result won't have much to do with population statistics.

Comment: I know it's vague. But the ask is given limited data points and assume normal distribution, how to predict.

Comment: So, fix the normal you want to use and the compute the expected value of the normal, conditioned on the draw being at least the observed age.

Comment: Is there a formula for this? Can it be written as a function f(u, x)? Sorry for my ignorance on expected value. Thanks

Comment: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166273/expected-value-of-x-in-a-normal-distribution-given-that-it-is-below-a-certain-v) is a discussion.  Of course, they are working it conditioned on the level being *below* a fixed value, but it's the same idea.

Comment: And [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills_ratio#Inverse_Mills_ratio) is a discussion of the Inverse Mills ratio.

Comment: Thanks I'll go over this. but it seems dense. I guess it will be integral over this probability density function? No simple function I guess.

Comment: Let suppose that probability of lifespan more that $t$ years is $f(t)$. Then expected lifespan at condition that person age is $x$ will be equal $P(x)=\frac{\int_x^{\infty} t f'(t)\, dt}{f(x)}$.